# bash to remove files from a file passed as a variable

Tags: bash

I asked this once before but now the below `bash` seems to delete and download all the files in the input file. Basically all the lines (6) in input are files and are read into the `$line` variable.  When I `echo` the `$line` I can see the files there and they do get deleted, but they also get downloaded and I dont need them to be, I am also not sure why they do.  Thank you :).

**strong text**

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file1.pdf
file2.pdf
file3.pdf
```

**bash**

```
# add filenames as variable and remove files from list
while read line; do
echo $line  (only there to verify that the files are in the variable)   
wget --user=xxxxx --password=xxx --xxxx --method=DELETE \
xxx://www.example.com/xx/xxx/xxx/$line
done < /home/cmccabe/list
rm /home/cmccabe/list
```

Comment: This is a wget issue, not a bash issue. What are you expecting the wget call to do?

Comment: When you use variables like this: xxx://www.example.com/xx/xxx/xxx/$line, you should enclose the whole string or at least the variable into double quotes, like this: "xxx://www.example.com/xx/xxx/xxx/$line". It will prevent you of any possible syntax errors in case when source file contains something like: "my cool file with spaces.txt".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-O /dev/null` option i.e.:

```
wget --user=xxxxx --password=xxx --xxxx --method=DELETE \
xxx://www.example.com/xx/xxx/xxx/$line -O /dev/null
```

To discard `wget's` output and avoid saving the output file.

Comment: Thank you all very much :).